# Android Studio VM not working

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-machine

My sample app is working only a VM having:

*- API:21

 - Target:5.0.1
 - CPU:arm*

Otherwise it says:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

**what i am suppose to do ?**

Answer (score 0):

HAX support requires some steps, check out this guide : [Installation Instructions for Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager - Microsoft Windows*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)

Comment: Do you computer support Intel Virtualization Technology (Intel VT-x), is it enabled in BIOS?

Comment: if that is the problem then why it is working for that VM which i mentioned above?

Comment: Because ARM does not use **Intel** HAXM, x86 system image does.
To enable VT-X through BIOS:
http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios